# AWS Lex and Facebook Ads integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-ads-api, amazon-lex

I am wondering would it be possible to integrate facebook ads with Lex? I mean this :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/ads

If it is , is there a documentation or example somewhere?

thanks
-m